# SAML configuration in Kubernetes deployment file

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, devops, saml

I need to use theSAML 2.0 Authentication (https://www.bookstackapp.com/docs/admin/saml2-auth/) in the Kubernetes deployment file of BookStack.

Is it possible to configure the variables from the above link in the Kubernetes deployment file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Look into this example - seems it was created just for you :)
https://github.com/BookStackApp/BookStack/issues/1776

Just use own variables in the deployment file from [saml2-auth](https://www.bookstackapp.com/docs/admin/saml2-auth/) page

```
apiVersion: "apps/v1"
kind: "Deployment"
metadata:
  name: "bookstack-test-x5"
  namespace: "default"
  labels:
    app: "bookstack-test-x5"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: "bookstack-test-x5"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: "bookstack-test-x5"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: "bookstack-sha256"
        image: "gcr.io/<PATH_TO_MY_CONTAINER>"
        env:
        - name: "DB_USER"
          value: "bookstack22"
        - name: "DB_HOST"
          value: "127.0.0.1"
        - name: DB_PORT
          value: "3306"
        - name: DB_DATABASE
          value: "bookstack"
        - name: "DB_PSWD"
          value: "my_secret_passowrd"
        - name: "APP_DEBUG"
          value: "true"
        - name: CACHE_DRIVER
          value: "database"
        - name: SESSION_DRIVER
          value: "database"
```